# efficient expanding linregress

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a dataframe that contains two columns (X and Y coordinates). I need the expanding linear regression from the start of the df. For example at the 2nd point I need the regression of the first 2 points; at the 3rd point I need it for the first 3 points, and so on. As per the docs, for functions with one input and one output [expanding_apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/computation.html#expanding-window-moment-functions) can be used, but linregress gives 5 outputs.

Currently I'm doing a for loop over all rows, which works fine but is unsurprisingly very slow, to the point of being barely usable.

I tried a couple things but was met with rejection. Tried sending inputs as a tuple:

```
pd.expanding_apply((df.x, df.y), linregress)
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Tried sending inputs as a df:

```
pd.expanding_apply(df[['x','y']], linregress)
> IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Each regression is almost identical to the one before (with just one added data point) so presumably there's a huge amount of room for speed up. Is there any way to achieve this in pandas or in the numpy/scipy domain that would be more efficient?

**Edit**: linregress optionally accepts a 2 dimensional array (instead of 2 separate one dimensional arrays), so `linregress(df[['x','y']])` on its own works fine. However `expanding_apply` is probably expecting a series for the arg, instead of a df.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute the linear regression parameters of `y = a*x + b`, you have to solve an overdetermined system of equations, `X*a = y`, where:

```
X = [[1, x0], [1, x1], ..., [1, x(n-1)]]
a = [b, a]
y = [ y0, y1, ..., y(n-1)]
```

If you are only after the values of `a` and `b`, you can premultiply both sides of your system by `X.T`, and solve the resulting 2x2 system. Taking a closer look, the resulting arrays can be written as:

```
np.dot(X.T, X) = [[n, np.sum(x)],
                  [np.sum(x), np.sum(x*x)]]
np.dot(X.T, y) = [np.sum(y), np.sum(x*y)]
```

Putting all this together, given two 1D arrays `x` and `y` of equal length, you could do the following with numpy >= 1.8:

```
n = 10
x, y = np.random.rand(2, n)

lhs = np.empty((n-1, 2, 2))
rhs = np.empty((n-1, 2))

lhs[:, 0, 0] = np.arange(2, n+1)
lhs[:, 0, 1] = np.cumsum(x)[1:]
lhs[:, 1, 0] = lhs[:, 0, 1]
lhs[:, 1, 1] = np.cumsum(x*x)[1:]

rhs[:, 0] = np.cumsum(y)[1:]
rhs[:, 1] = np.cumsum(x*y)[1:]

a = np.linalg.solve(lhs, rhs)
```

You can check that `a` holds the right parameters comparing with the result of `polyfit`:

```
In [49]: a
Out[49]:
array([[ 0.64778976, -0.39918768],
       [ 0.76225593, -0.41054035],
       [ 0.72598372, -0.35430181],
       [ 0.70608159, -0.33873589],
       [ 0.6899674 , -0.34941498],
       [ 0.68270772, -0.34834723],
       [ 0.71031366, -0.59487271],
       [ 0.7422803 , -0.74757567],
       [ 0.65982282, -0.48593478]])

In [50]: for j in range(2, n+1):
   ....:     print np.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit(x[:j], y[:j], 1)
   ....:
[ 0.64778976 -0.39918768]
[ 0.76225593 -0.41054035]
[ 0.72598372 -0.35430181]
[ 0.70608159 -0.33873589]
[ 0.6899674  -0.34941498]
[ 0.68270772 -0.34834723]
[ 0.71031366 -0.59487271]
[ 0.7422803  -0.74757567]
[ 0.65982282 -0.48593478]
```

Comment: Thank you for what looks like a perfect answer. I'll admit to not being familiar with numpy so I'll play with it a bit to make sure I understand what's going on. I got your sample to work after changing to `np.linalg.solve` (I guess our imports are different).

Comment: Perfect, not only does it work and match linregress, it's more than 300x faster than what I was doing. Thank you!